# How to add a static image inbetween the product tiles on main shoppage woocommerce?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

This is the first time i'm asking for help online so keepin' my fingers crossed.

I was wondering if it's possible to add an ( static / clickable ) image inbetween the products on my main woocommerce shop page. The purpose is to visually break the long list of products that is shown. Preferably the same size as the product tile.

[image: preview website main shop page]

as shown in the picture i would like the entire tile to be an image.

hope anybody can help me!

Maybe it's wise to explain that i'm not a very skilled programmer. More of a self thought programmer that uses reversed engeneering and a lot of trail and error, to figure out how to tweek and change things ( html, php etc )

thanks.
peer

Comment: There's probably dozens of ways to achieve what you want but it's hard to tell you how to do it without seeing what you're working with.  Who built the theme, do you have access to edit it, did you make your own template or are you using the default WooCommerce template?
You'll need to start by augmenting your own version of the shop template from WooCommerce and then once you've got some working code, come back and add it to your question.  Also, where is the image being set, where is the link for the image being set, how are those values retrieved? etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.